# Apply Angular binding on dynamic HTML

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to Angular and maybe trying to use it in incorrect way, but..
I have this code - input to enter url and link to go to that url.

```
<div>
    <input type="text" ng-model="url0">
    <a href="{{url0}}">goto</label>
</div>
```

Cool, href attribute is now synchronized with input.
Now I want to clone this div, replacing url0 to url1. But how to make binding work on new div?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You'll need to make an effort and ask a more specific question related to your attempt. I'd look into `ngRepeat` and `$index`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stop thinking in terms of DOM manipulation. DOM manipulation is evil. Angular is designed to allow avoiding DOM manipulation as much as possible.

Think in terms of objects and arrays in the model, and a template which displays this model.

So, for example:

```
$scope.items = [
    {
        url: 'foo';
    }
];

$scope.addItem = function() {
    $scope.items.push({
        url: '';
    });
};
```

And in the template:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <input type="text" ng-model="item.url">
    <a ng-href="{{item.url}}">goto</a>
</div>
<button ng-click="addItem()">Add an item</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Manipulating the DOM using Angular is not recommended. This is how I would do it:

HTML:

```
<input id="url-input" type="text"/>
<button id="go-button">GO</button>
```

JS:

```
var input,
    go_button,
    url;

input = document.getElementById("url-input");
go_button = document.getElementById("go-button");

go_button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    url = input.value;
    window.location.href = url;
});
```